# How to write 'not parents'

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove everything except for a certain 'selection' which consist out of span and its parents:

```
$('*').not('span:parents').remove();
```

This doesn't work for me, tried numerous things with no luck.

Comment: It would help if you could post the HTML you want to apply this to.

Comment: Is using a class out of the question?

Comment: @ j08691 You mean there is nothing wrong with the code and it should work..?

Comment: @Youss - I don't mean that at all. I mean it would help us understand exactly what you're trying to do if you posted your HTML.

Comment: @j08691 Well its a long story, Im scraping websites so I really dont know what the HTML is to begin with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of selecting all elements, just select the top level ones that have to be removed, any child of `body` which does not have the `span` element(s) as descendant:

```
$('body').children().not($('span').parents()).remove();
```

`$('span').parents()` will also contain the child of `body` which has to be kept.

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/BaLAb/

Comment: well... That's simpler than my solution and it still avoids using the '*' selector. +1

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to save the elements, remove the rest, then put it again :

```
var saved = $('#a').closest('body>*').detach();
$(document.body).children().remove();
$(document.body).append(saved);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ocumer/1/edit)

EDIT : use Felix's answer, you don't have to save and put back in fact...

Comment: I like the `body>*` selector... didn't think about that. But I think `.find('>*')` won't work, wasn't a leading `>` in selectors deprecated at some point? You can always use `.children` though ;)

Comment: @FelixKling yes, I was trying and concluded the same. Your answer is still better, though.